# Will I kill my computer if I delete this partition? Contains BootInfo, boot-sav, lost+found...

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, partitioning

I want to delete a partition to save some space, but I want to make sure it doesn't have anything important on it. All it has are the following three directories, which look important, maybe...

```
BootInfo/  boot-sav/  lost+found/
```

Does anyone know what these folders contain? Will I be deleting my machine's bootloader, or some other vital organ, if I delete this partition?

Running Ubuntu 12.04. Partition size 13g, used 161M, at /dev/sda8.

Comment: output from `mount` would be useful

Comment: `mount` shows nothing about the partition. does that mean it's not mounted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The safest thing you could do to save space it to just resize it down 161M(you can use gparted)

With Linux the file location for the bootloader is /boot depending on how you installed it, the /boot could be on the Ubuntu partition or on it's own partition.

These are Ubuntu created file but are not critical to boot or system, they are diagnostic and repair tools, so maybe it might be a better idea to just resize the partition